# How to see if a value in a spreadsheet cell is present in its corresponding text file?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to see if the company's revenue is present in its corresponding txt file (File Path in Column C). And indicate in Column D if the revenue listed is present or not?

[image]

Was wondering if there was an Excel Macro in VBA for my situation?

Thanks,

EDIT: I think I have something, but I'm trying to figure out how to loop this code to the next rows

```
Sub SearchTextFile()
Dim strFileName As String
strFileName = Sheet1.Range("C2").Value
Dim strSearch As Long
strSearch = Sheet1.Range("b2").Value
Dim strLine As String
Dim f As Integer
Dim lngLine As Long
Dim blnFound As Boolean
f = FreeFile
Open strFileName For Input As #f
Do While Not EOF(f)
    lngLine = lngLine + 1
    Line Input #f, strLine
    If InStr(1, strLine, strSearch, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
        Sheet1.Range("D2") = "Yes"
        MsgBox "Revenue is In the File"
        blnFound = True
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
Close #f
If Not blnFound Then
    Sheet1.Range("D2") = "No"
    MsgBox "Search string not found", vbInformation
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You most likely will need to write something.

Comment: Just a pointer - use [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa(v=vs.84).aspx) to read (line by line or all at once) and locate desired text, either as a **Sub** or User Defined **Function** with those A,B,C as input.

Comment: @TimWilliams Here is the code I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can loop in your macro:

```
Sub SearchTextFile()
Dim rowCount as Long
rowCount = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
For i = 2 To rowCount
'Your code here. Use "i" as a row indicator, e.g. strFileName = Sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I incorporated this in my code and it worked! I appreciate the help